# Kstream transformValues ambigious

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have problem with ambiguous methods in KStream.

Actually I don't understand what is wrong.

```
.toStream()
        .transformValues(
            ValueTransformerWithKeySupplier<String, CandleDto, CandleDto> {
                SuppressTransformer<String, CandleDto, CandleDto>(
                    Duration.ofMinutes(5),
                    "supress-store",
                    Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            },
            "suppress-store"
        )
```

This code result into this:
[image]

```
class SuppressTransformer<K, V, VR>(
    private val windowSize: Duration,
    private val storeName: String,
    private val scheduleTime: Duration
) : ValueTransformerWithKey<K, V, VR> {
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: Please show the actual compilation error text. Those methods all have different method signatures (read the Javadoc). They are not ambiguous. E.g. You have no `Named` object here, so the 2nd and 3rd options aren't valid for your use-case. And you aren't using `ValueTransformerSupplier` type, so neither is the 4th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I just realize what is wrong (because i'm blind). Thanks @OneCricketeer, your answer forced me to look logs once more :-)

Error was caused because I use windowing before transformation.
And I had to map values before start transformation.

Now it is compilable:

```
        .map { key, value -> KeyValue.pair(key.key(), Mapper.toCandle(value)) }
        .transformValues(
            ValueTransformerWithKeySupplier<String, Candle, Candle> {
                SuppressTransformer<String, Candle,Candle>(
                    Duration.ofMinutes(5),
                    "suppress-store",
                    Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            },
            "suppress-store"
        )
```

Comment: You might want to mark your own answer as "accepted".